# Learning float numbers length

Tags: python, command

Is there any command like `len()` to measure length of float number?

when I try : `len(a[k])` *(a[k] is the array, which gives random float numbers)*:

there is an error like the following:

```
object of type 'float' has no len()
```

---

My code:

```
import random
a=[random.uniform(10,100) for i in range (1000)]

c= open("dosya.txt","w")
c.write('X DEGER:  Y DEGER:\n')
c.write('--------------\n')

count = 0.0
while count < 99.9:
count +=0.1
c.write ("%s\n" % count)    


c=open("dosya.txt","w")
c.seek(37,0)
for k in range(900):
    print a[k]
    c.write(", %.2f" %(a[k]))
    c.seek(len(str(a[k])),1)    
    c.close
```

I want to create two columns in the file, but second loops the numbers, owerwritng on the first one.

For example,

```
 0.1  38.582   
 0.2  58.214                        
 0.3  16.427
```

but the output is like:

```
 0.1 38.585
 0.3 25.420 
 0.5 47.543
```

As you see the float number overwriting `0.2`.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the float to a string using [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), then measure the length:

```
>>> len(str(2.34))
4
```

Or, if you don't want it to count the decimal, remove it:

```
>>> len(str(2.34).replace('.',''))
3
```

Obviously, you can replace `2.34` with `a[k]` :).

Comment: could ı use like  : ** c.seek(5+len(str(a[k]),1) **

Comment: c.seek(5+len(str(a[k]),1)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @nuri_ Oh, sorry, you forgot a `)`. Put a `)` after `len(str(a[k])`

Comment: @nuri_ You need another to close `len(`

Comment: there is still syntaxError : ıf u can gımme your maıl adress ı wıll send whole code to advise

Comment: @nuri_ I will not be doing that. The correct code should be: 

`c.seek(5+len(str(a[k])), 1)`

Comment: @nuri_ Please edit your question and show the full code. That couldn't possibly raise an error, let alone a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
len(str(a[k]))
```

This converts the float to a string and finds out the length of the string, and thus that of the float.

If you don't want to count the point, you can do

```
len(str(a[k])) - 1
```

Comment: could ı wrote : *** c.seek(5+len(str(a[k]),1) ***